# The current path, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django

Ive been trying to implement the reset password processs of django but something is not working, I know from the error that there is a url pattern that does not exit but from where accounts/login came from,It worked fine before but my colleague took my laptop and after that this happened

urls.py

```
 """travel URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('loginpage.urls')),
    path('signup/',include('signup.urls')),
    path('homepage/',include('Homepage.urls')),
    path('password_reset/',auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='loginpage/resetpassword.html'),name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset_sent/',auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='loginpage/password_resent_sent.html'),name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='loginpage/password_reset_form.html'),name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('Password_changed_succesfully/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='loginpage/password_reset_done.html'),name='password_reset_complete')
]
```

resetpassword.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% load static %}
    <title>Reset Password</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="{% static 'reset.css' %}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="right"><img src="{% static 'images/logo2.png' %}" height="400" width="400"></div>
    <div class="main">      
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk" aria-hidden="true">

            <div class="resett">
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form}}
                        <input type='submit' name=" Send email">
                </form>
            </div>
    </div>>

</body>
</html>
```

password_reset_form.html

```
<h3>Password reset sent</h3>


<p>We’ve emailed you instructions for setting your password, if an account exists with the email you entered. You should receive them shortly.</p>

<p>If you don’t receive an email, please make sure you’ve entered the address you registered with, and check your spam folder.</p>
```

password_reset_done.html:

```
<h3>Password reset complete</h3>

<p>Your password has been set. You may go ahead and log in now.</p>

<a href="{% url loginpage:check_user %}">Log in</a>
```

Error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/Password_changed_succesfully/
Using the URLconf defined in travel.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='check_user']
signup/
homepage/
password_reset/ [name='password_reset']
password_reset_sent/ [name='password_reset_done']
reset/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='password_reset_confirm']
Password_changed_succesfully/ [name='password_reset_complete']
The current path, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Comment: What's inside loginpage.urls ?

Comment: Underscores should not be used for URL's (`Password_changed_succesfully`)